# C++: delete this; return x;

Tags: c++, free

Hey I am curious about some C++ behaviour as the code I am working on would benefit greatly from this in terms of simplicity if this behaviour is consistent. Basically the idea is for a specific function inside my object `A` to compute a complex calculation returning a `float`, but just before returning the `float`, occasionally, calling `delete this`.

---

**1**

here is a code example of the functionality i am trying to verify is consistent.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    float test(float a) {delete this; return a;}
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new A();
    cout << a->test(1.f) << endl;
    cout << "deleted?" << endl;
    cout << a->test(1.f) << endl;
}
```

the output becomes:

```
1.0
deleted?
*** Error in `./test': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0105d008 *** Aborted (core dumped)
```

I think this means the object was deleted correctly (what is left in memory? an uncallable skeleton of A? A typed pointer? A null pointer?), but am not sure whether I am right about that. If so, is this behaviour going to be consistent (my functions will only be returning native types (floats))

---

**2**

Additionally I am curious as to why this doesn't seem to work:

```
struct A
{
    float test(float a) {delete this; return a;}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    cout << a.test(1.f) << endl;
}
```

this compiles but throws the following error before returning anything.

```
*** Error in `./test': free(): invalid pointer: 0xbe9e4c64 *** Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

**NOTE** Please don't tell reply with a long list of explanations as to why this is bad coding/etiquette or whatever, don't care, I am simply interested in the possibilities.

Comment: `delete this;` has it's uses, but isn't a good idea usually.

Comment: Using a pointer after deleting what it points leads to *undefined behavior*. It's most definitely not going to be "consistent". Likewise with attempting to delete memory not allocated by you using `new`.

Comment: If your question is simply "Is this crash consistent?" then technically the answer is no, this is undefined behaviour.  But in practice, nothing good can ever come of invoking `delete this` on a stack-allocated object.

Comment: It just isn't clear what you're asking. Your code is totally broken but you don't want people to tell you that.

Comment: @user2255757: So, what is your question intended to be about? Accessing deallocated memory? Or performing an illegal `delete` (repetitive `delete` or `delete` on local memory)? The question you ask seem to target both of these issues, but in reality they are completely separate and have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safe for a member function to call `delete this;` *if* you know that the object was allocated using scalar `new` and that nothing else will use the object afterward.

In your first example, after the first call to `a->test(1.f)`, `a` becomes a "dangling pointer".  You invoke Undefined Behavior when you dereference it to call `test` a second time.

In your second example, the `delete this;` statement is Undefined Behavior because the object was not created using `new`.

Comment: @user2255757 - Not in any portable way.  If you find yourself needing to do so, you're already "doing it wrong", design-wise.

Comment: i only want the succesfull call to first a->test

Comment: thank you for not just assing and taking the question serious, so basically me fear was correct that I am stuck with what i guess is called a dangling pointer

Comment: @user2255757 _"i only want the succesfull call to first a->test"_ Why do you wan't to do this in 1st place? What's your use case?

Comment: @user2255757: Your calls to `a->test()` are *already* as successful as they can ever be. But what you do inside those calls is what causes your code to crash. And no, there's no way to make double-free to be "successful".

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is undefined, but in a typical modern implementation the practical "possibilities" of accessing deallocated memory include (but not limited to):

1. `delete` releases memory at run-time library level (RTL), but does not return it to the OS. I.e. OS-level memory protection is not engaged and OS continues to see that memory as allocated. However, internal RTL data stored in freed memory blocks clobbers your data. The result: access through the pointer does not cause your code to crash, but the data looks meaningless (clobbered)
2. Same as 1, but internal RTL data happens not to overlap your critical data. The code does not crash and continues to work "as if" everything is "fine".
3. `delete` releases memory to the OS. OS-level memory protection is engaged. Any attempt to access though the pointer causes an immediate crash.

Your examples proceed in accordance with the second scenario, i.e. the data stored in the object appears to remain untouched even after you free the memory.

The crashes you observe in your code happen because RTL detects a double `free` attempt (or an attempt to `free` a non-dynamic memory, as in the second example), which is kinda besides the point in the context of your question.